# MT9721K wireless adapter Drivers randomly stop working on debian and ubuntu based systems

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, touchpad, uptime

After a certain amount of uptime, the OS is irreversably unable to detect the wireless adapter (MT7921K in this case). I previously "fixed" this by restoring the original Windows 11 install and then installing Debian 12 -- this worked, but I didn't realize long uptimes were the cause and now it has once again stopped working.

I found [this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380400/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts) but unlike that user, it seems like I have multiple aliases assigned to the mt7921e module. I'm not sure how to solve this problem, and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86
Host: Modern 14 C7M REV:1.0
Kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64

Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz [14c3:0608]
    Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921K (RZ608) Wi-Fi 6E 80MHz [14c3:0608]

user@localhost ~> sudo modinfo mt7921e | grep alias
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

Update: I followed the advice in [this](https://www.linux.org/threads/wifi-adaptator-not-found-mediatek-wi-fi-6-mt7921-wireless.39584/post-154555) post and did a 60-second hold on the power button. Upon rebooting there was a "secure boot violation". I disabled secure boot and booted successfully into the desktop to find that my wifi was indeed working. However, my touchpad has stopped working.

Update 2: On the previous boot I had my mouse plugged in during boot. I removed the mouse and rebooted, and after booting the touchpad was recognized and the mouse worked as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice in [this](https://www.linux.org/threads/wifi-adaptator-not-found-mediatek-wi-fi-6-mt7921-wireless.39584/post-154555) post and did a 60-second hold on the power button. Upon rebooting there was a "secure boot violation". I disabled secure boot and booted successfully into the desktop to find that my wifi was indeed working.